# PHP create dynamic array in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to dynamic create an array based on a number inside a multidimensional array

here is the code

```
$meta_box = array(  
'id' => 'my-meta-box',
'title' => 'Custom Input Fields',
'page' => 'page',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'fields' => array (
                  array( //this array must be created dynamic 
                      'name' => 'Textarea',
                      'desc' => 'Enter big text here',
                      'id' => 'textarea', //id is textarea + number
                      'type' => 'textarea',
                      'std' => 'Default value'
                  )
            )
);
```

I want the last array to be created dynamic by a number so if the number is 2 there must be 2 arrays in there with the same name,desc,type,str but a diffrent ID.

is this possible is somekind of way?

Comment: Have you tried creating the array using a loop?

Comment: can you give me an example how cause im really stuck

Comment: Show some code you have and tell us what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add them dynamically by iterating over the number of ids:

```
$meta_box = array
(
    'id' => 'my-meta-box',
    'title' => 'Custom Input Fields',
    'page' => 'page',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array ()
);


$dynamicNumber = 2;
$idPrefix = 'textarea';
assert('$dynamicNumber > 0');
$dynamicIds = range(1, $dynamicNumber);

$fields = &$meta_box['fields'];
foreach($dynamicIds as $id)
{
    $fields[] = array( //this array must be created dynamic 
                      'name' => 'Textarea',
                      'desc' => 'Enter big text here',
                      'id' => sprintf('%s%d', $idPrefix, $id), //id is textarea + number
                      'type' => 'textarea',
                      'std' => 'Default value'
                  );
}
unset($fields);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/WhnTyOZa)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to add each 'fields' sub array as a new array into the larger array

```
$meta_box = array(  
'id' => 'my-meta-box',
'title' => 'Custom Input Fields',
'page' => 'page',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high');

$fields = array();

$numberOfArrays = 2;

for($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfArrays; $i++){
    $fields[$i] = array (
                  array( //this array must be created dynamic 
                      'name' => 'Textarea',
                      'desc' => 'Enter big text here',
                      'id' => 'textarea' . $i, //id is textarea + number
                      'type' => 'textarea',
                      'std' => 'Default value'
                  )
            );
}

$meta_box['fields'] = $fields;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($meta_box);
echo '</pre>';
```

You'll get an output like this in your browser:

```
Array
(
    [id] => my-meta-box
    [title] => Custom Input Fields
    [page] => page
    [context] => normal
    [priority] => high
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                            [name] => Textarea
                            [desc] => Enter big text here
                            [id] => textarea1
                            [type] => textarea
                            [std] => Default value
                )
        [2] => Array
                (
                            [name] => Textarea
                            [desc] => Enter big text here
                            [id] => textarea2
                            [type] => textarea
                            [std] => Default value
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/pNkN7GG9)

Answer (score 0):

First you create the array $meta_box as follows:

```
$meta_box = array(  
  'id' => 'my-meta-box',
  'title' => 'Custom Input Fields',
  'page' => 'page',
  'context' => 'normal',
  'priority' => 'high',
  'fields' => array ()
);
```

Then you can add the 'dynamic' arrays as follows:

```
$number = 2;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
  $meta_box['fields'][] = array(
    'name' => 'Textarea',
    'desc' => 'Enter big text here',
    'id' => 'textarea_' . $i, //id is textarea + number
    'type' => 'textarea',
    'std' => 'Default value'
  );
}
```

This starts the numbering for the ids at 1 until $number.